# Word 2013 Formula: Why does not the TRUE function work?

Tags: ms-word

I'm trying to use the `TRUE` function in a Word table, but I only get a syntax error I can't interpret. Two similar functions work just fine. What could be wrong?

My simple table with 2 columns and 3 rows has the following functions specified:

```
function             return
=OR(1=1;1=5)         1
=TRUE(1=1)           !Syntax Error, (
=NOT(1=1)            0
```

Formula reference:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/use-a-formula-in-a-word-table-HA102329800.aspx#_Toc281293376

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the documentation you link to is for Word 2007 and 2010 and not for 2013. However, I agree with you - this looks like a documentation bug.

On [this documentation page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-formula-field-HA102017594.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102749146) I found the documented behavior of the `TRUE` function in Word 2007, 2010, and 2013 to be defined as: always return `1` - explaining why you get the syntax error.

So ye, the two pages definitely contradicts each other, but I would go the the documentation page I provided, since it covers Word 2013 as well (which appears to be the version you are working with).

Comment: Hi! Yes, you are correct that I'm using 2013, but I actually also tried it in 2010 when I saw the documentation I used was for 2010. Microsoft has a strange way of providing documentation sometimes. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: No problem :) I guess your question is answered then, so it would be great if you would mark one of the answers as accepted - then new visitors can easily find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: I was planning the mark my own as the answer but I cant do that until two days from now, so you get the mark :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as TRUE dos not take any arguments. It only returns a 1, as FALSE only returns a 0.

```
function             return
=TRUE                1
=FALSE               0
```

So the documentation is wrong, I suppose.